# Hide <p:commandButton>

Tags: html, primefaces

I have used  in my xhtml page to display command buttons. Now I want an implementation such that there is a commandButton which calls a javascript and if my condition matches then I'll call another command Button which is hidden. Is there any way I can make my second commandButton hidden. 
My only issue is to make commandButton hidden.

Comment: style="display:none"  with <p:commandButton> it worked for me. However, your suggestion is also correct.

Comment: No, the suggestion to use `rendered` is not correct. If the button is not rendered, then you can't "call" it with JS, since it won't exist on the client at all.

Comment: using `style="display:none"` is only client-side and prone to tampering. Might not be a real risk in your use-case, but keep it in mind